# How to evaluate and process a simple string syntax-tree in C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a corpus of token-index based documents which offers a query method. The user manually(!) enters a query string which needs to be parsed and evaluated. The corpus should then return a list of all documents matching the given query string. The query language features the simple boolean operators AND, NOT and OR which can also be prioritized by parenthesis.
After some research I already used ANTLR to parse a given query string into a syntax tree.

For example: The query

```
"Bill OR (John AND Jim) OR (NOT Simon AND Mike)"
```

is translated in the following syntax tree:

**EDIT: Please see the correct graph in Bart Kiers post (copied here):**

[image]

All nodes in the tree are simple strings and each node knows its parent and children but not its siblings. 
As you can see, the ANTLR grammar already dictated the order in which the operations need to be executed: the ones at the bottom of the tree come first.

So what I probably need to do is recusively(?) evaluate all operands in the tree.
In general, I can do a simple search on my corpus using a method Get(string term) for each leaf in the tree (like "Bill" or "John"). Get() returns a list of documents containing the term in the leaf. I can also evaluate the parent of each leaf to recognize a possible NOT operator which would then lead to a result list of documents NOT containing the term in the leaf (using the method Not() instead of Get()).

The AND and OR operator should be transformed into method calls which need two parameters:

- AND should call a method Intersect(list1, list2) which returns a list of documents that are in list1 AND in list2.
- OR should call a method Union(list1, list2) which returns a list of documents that are either in list1 OR in list2.

The parameters list1 and list2 contain the documents I received before using Get() or Not().

My question is: How can I - semantically and syntactically in C# - evaluate all necessary search terms and use them to call the right operator methods in the correct order? Intuitively it sounds like recursion but somehow I can't picture it - especially since not all methods that need to be called have the same amount of parameters. Or are there maybe entirely other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Completely off-topic, but what tool did you use to make that graphic?

Comment: Should "NOT Simon" return a set of everyone but Simon, or an expression that would evaluate false for Simon, or what...?

Comment: @Cameron: Microsoft PowerPoint 2010 with integrated quick formatting:)

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: "NOT Simon" would return a set with all entries (documents) that don't contain the string "Simon". You can imagine the operands in the context of querying Google.

Comment: Seems like a natural fit for building an `ExpressionTree` with recursion. Then you can use it as a predicate on any `IEnumerable`. I'm not familiar with ANTLR but maybe I can write some pseudo code.

Comment: If you were to query google for all documents NOT containing specific words, I would doubt Google would construct a set of all those documents, I would assume it would first find all the documents matching the positive query operators, and then filter those against the negative ones. Unless your list of documents is manageable that is.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify things up.

Comment: Why not create the tree first, and then do a simple recursive Eval? Or is that not possible in antlr? Having the tree handy will allow you to do other stuff, like transform to optimize the 'query plan' etc.

Comment: I do have the tree but I don't know how to write that Eval function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pseudo Code

```
Set Eval (Tree t) {

    switch (t.Operator) {
        case OR:
             Set result = emptySet;
             foreach(child in T.Children) {
                 result = Union(result, Eval(child));
             }
             return result;
        case AND:
             Set result = UniversalSet;
             foreach(child in T.Children) {
                 result = Intersection(result, Eval(child));
             }
             return result;
        case blah: // Whatever.
    }
    // Unreachable.
}
```

Does that help?

Or were you looking to optimize the order of evaluations, which probably has books written on it...

Comment: Ha, I finally got it! Sorry for the late reaction but I need a while and Bart's help to completely understand your solution (especially because I didn't realize that AND/OR always have exactly two parameters). With slight corrections (e.g. in your code, you are always intersecting an empty set with the results of the children) this is what I finally did and it totally works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would have expected the following tree to be generated:

[image]

*(note that in your AST, the `OR` node has 3 children)*

Either way, if you have created an ANTLR grammar that is able to create an AST (whether in the form of your original image, or mine posted above), it means that you have defined the proper operator precedence in your grammar. In that case, you shouldn't be confused to execute the order of your operators since your tree already mandates that `(John <- AND -> Jim)` and `(NOT -> Simon)` are to be evaluated first.

Could you perhaps post the ANTLR grammar you've been working on?

Also, you're talking about sets, but in your example, only single values are shown, so I get the impression your language is a bit more complex than you've shown so far. Perhaps you could explain your actual language, instead of a dumbed-down version of it?

**PS**. The source that created the image can be found here: http://graph.gafol.net/elDKbwzbA (ANTLR grammar also incuded)

Comment: Oh sorry, you're absolutely right - my grammar (which is basically the same as yours) indeed generates your tree and not mine! What I as a total ANTLR newbie - still don't get is how I can extract the operators and parameters in the right order from that tree. Again, this could be a basic recursion which I don't see or maybe a feature on the AST object? The other problem is that for example "Simon" is not the real operand of NOT but needs to be evaluated first by the Not() method which then returns a list of documents containing the term "Simon" (this result list is what I named "set").

Comment: @SimonW, quote: _"... returns a list of documents containing the term "Simon" ..."_, I presume you meant: _"... returns a list of documents **not** containing the term "Simon" ..."_

Comment: Yeah.. damn, I am kinda nervous and unconcentrated at the moment ;) I am currently editing my inital post to clarify things up - please stay tuned.

Comment: I hope I'm not the one making you nervous... :)

Comment: You probably are but in a good way! I hope my setup and problem now appear much clearer to you and the others. Thank you btw for your comment concerning my wrong tree. I didn't realize before that one operation can't have more than two parameters which is a good thing...

Comment: @SimonW, your question is clear now (at least, to me it is). However, I am not proficient enough in C# to answer your question. I do know a bit about ANTLR and Java, so if you know a bit Java, I could post a quick guide how evaluate your expressions in Java.

Comment: I just heard from the _Mrs_ it's passed my bed time, so if you do want me to post some Java demo, I'll do so tomorrow.

Comment: No problem, +1 and thanks again for your great answer - it helped me alot to understand the real problem! I actually implemented it like Moron suggested and it works like a charm now. While I'm sorry that I can only mark one answer as "right", the good news is that you don't have to code anything now ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the object model which ANTLR generates but assuming its something like this:

```
class BinaryNode : Node
{
    public Node LeftChild;
    public Node RightChild;            
    public readonly string Operator;            
}

class UnaryNode : Node
{
    public Node Child;
    public readonly string Operator;
}

class TerminalNode : Node
{
    public readonly string LeafItem;
}

class Node { }

public class Executor
{
    public IEnumerable<object> Get(string value)
    {
        return null;
    }
    public IEnumerable<object> GetAll()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetItems(Node node)
    {
        if (node is TerminalNode)
        {
            var x = node as TerminalNode;
            return Get(x.LeafItem);
        }
        else if (node is BinaryNode)
        {
            var x = node as BinaryNode;
            if (x.Operator == "AND")
            {
                return GetItems(x.LeftChild).Intersect(GetItems(x.RightChild));
            }
            else if (x.Operator == "OR")
            {
                return GetItems(x.LeftChild).Concat(GetItems(x.RightChild));
            }
        }
        else if (node is UnaryNode)
        {
            var x = node as UnaryNode;

            if (x.Operator == "NOT")
            {
                return GetAll().Except(GetItems(x.Child));
            }
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Note however this evaluates the query eagerly, which is not optimal. But it should give you an idea of how recursion would work.

Comment: +1 because I like the concept and might try this out later. For now I'll stick with the recursive algorithm supplied by Moron though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but I think I would turn the AST into a `Func<Person, bool>`. Each leaf node can be evaulated to a `Func<Person, bool>` for example `p => p.Name == "Bill"` AND, OR, and NOT can be implemented as higher order functions for example:

```
public static Func<T, bool> And<T>(Func<T, bool> a, Func<T, bool> b)
{
    return t => a(t) && b(T);
}
```

Once you've done all this and collapsed your AST into a single `Func<Person, bool>`, you can pass that as the parameter to the `Where()` extension method on any type that implements `IEnumerable<Person>`.

In other words, I would first "compile" the AST into a `Func<Person, boo>`, and then use LINQ to Objects to actually filter my collection. Compiling should be easy because your AST is an implementation of the Composite design pattern. Each node should be able to expose the method `Func<Person, bool> Compile()`.